# My Script works for some people but not others

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created an audit template in Google sheets that uses several scripts. The script is designed to populate a cell with the active user's email and a time date stamp when they click on a check box.  The script works, except for one person, the script does not recognize his active user email. Can someone tell me why the script works for some but not others and how I might fix it?

I've tested the script in a blank test spreadsheet and it works for this person. We had this same issue in another Google Sheet, but we remedied it my creating a new spreadsheet and copying all of the tabs and script. However, attempts to do the same with this spreadsheet have failed.

Here's my script:

```
function onEdit(e) {  //this is the event Google Sheets fires when cells are changed
var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); // Get the email address of the person running the script.
var date = new Date();
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == "InterimTestsOfControls") {   //only do this if the changed cell is on the specific worksheet you care about
  switch (e.range.getA1Notation()) {  //This gets the cell that was edited
    case "E5":                        //and this switch statement allows you to only respond to the cells you care about
      if (e.value == "TRUE") {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("F5").setValue("Prepared by " + email + " " + date);
        Logger.log(email);
        spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Audit Planning'), true).getRange('C7').activate().setValue(email);
        spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('InterimTestsOfControls'), true).getRange('C5').activate();
      }
      else {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("F5").setValue("Click box to sign-off as preparer");
        Logger.log(email);
        spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Audit Planning'), true).getRange('C7').activate().setValue("");
        spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('InterimTestsOfControls'), true).getRange('C5').activate();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please use the code sample feature and format the script so we can see it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

From the official [Session class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session) documentation:

> ### getActiveUser()
>
> Gets information about the current user. **If security policies do not allow access to the user's identity, User.getEmail() returns a blank string.**

This situation may happen under many, different circumstances:

- The user's email address is not available in any context that allows a script to run without that user's authorisation, like a **simple** `onOpen(e)` or `onEdit(e)` trigger, a custom function in Google Sheets, or a web app deployed to "execute as me" (that is, authorized by the developer instead of the user).
- These restrictions generally do not apply if the developer runs the script themselves or belongs to the same G Suite domain as the user.

In your situation I see that you are using a simple `onEdit(e)` trigger - so it looks like this may be the issue. You may want to check out [Installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {  
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); //This is a permissions issue.  You may have to use an installable trigger and even then it's not guaranteed
  var date = new Date();//you might want to use Utilities.formatDate()
  //var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();this is than same as e.source
  if (sh.getName()=="InterimTestsOfControls") {  
    //you can selection your cells with information that's already in the event block rather than having to run another function
    if(e.range.columnStart==6 && e.range.rowStart==5) {
      if (e.value=="TRUE") {
        sh.getRange("F5").setValue("Prepared by " + email + " " + date);
        e.source.getSheetByName('Audit Planning').getRange('C7').setValue(email);
      } else {
        e.source.getRange("F5").setValue("Click box to sign-off as preparer");
        e.source.getSheetByName('Audit Planning').getRange('C7').setValue("");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Getting and setting the active range is a remnant of the Macro Recorder following your every step and in general is not required in your scripts.  And in fact it will slow down your scripts so please try to avoid using that approach in general for most scripting.